# Theorists sure want true answers to this!

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography, anagram, acronym

> So, birds eat bread I toss.
>
> One romantic kiss in the rain's too nice, methinks.
>
> Untidy notes disrupted a student in a study period.
>
> Deodorant on to end an odor.
>
> The wisdom of anagrams fathoms a game in words.
>
> False hope helps a foe.
>
> I may be in prison for decades for my pea-brained decisions.
>
> Was in a bathtub to obtain a butt-wash.
>
> See all the children eat candy and chances are, teeth'll yield.

***What do all these sentences above have in common, exactly?***

---

P.S. I have room for one more tag, but if I add that particular tag, this puzzle will probably be solved in five minutes, so I will only include that tag once this puzzle has been solved with an accepted answer. There also may be many things in common with these sentences, so I stress the word "exactly" in the actual question.

> **Edit:** the tag has been officially added.

---

## Thank You!!!

Thank you to the users who upvoted this, and @El-Guest's correct and accepted answer! Thanks also to @El-Guest for even answering this question as quick as he/she did! It is because of you guys that my puzzle has made it in the *Top New Questions* of the PSE Newsletter, Monday, April $8$, $2019$!

I was so excited to have seen this when I checked my emails this morning, so again, I want to give a big thanks to you and, overall, this entire puzzling community! If it wasn't for this site and its amazing community, I would never have even known what the answer to this puzzle actually *was*.

So a huge shoutout to the entire site and what it stands for as a community, and I hope to be creating and answering more puzzles, over and over again! Once again, *thank you!!!* :D

Comment: Is the extra tag by any chance in the puzzle itself? :)

Comment: @noedne why, yes... ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

They are all

> SWIFT DUOS (from your upwards acrostic)

I’m guessing this means that the

> First half of each sentence anagrams to the second half

The

> Divisions are represented below by a tilde, per OP comments below...

Then

> So, birds eat ~ bread I toss. 
>  One romantic kiss in the ~ rain's too nice, methinks. 
>  Untidy notes disrupted a ~ student in a study period. 
>  Deodorant on ~ to end an odor. 
>  The wisdom of anagrams ~ fathoms a game in words. 
>  False hope ~ helps a foe. 
>  I may be in prison for decades ~ for my pea-brained decisions. 
>  Was in a bathtub to ~ obtain a butt-wash. 
>  See all the children eat candy ~ and chances are, teeth'll yield.

And the title:

> Theorists sure want ~ true answers to this!

Comment: Oh, come on! Turns out this puzzle was solved in five minutes after all xD $(+1)$ You are a bloody legend.

Comment: Thanks, @user477343 — I strive to be somewhat prophetic! Great puzzle!

Comment: I will give you the tick in $24$ hours from now, if you don't mind. Keep up the amazing work! :)

Comment: Oh, by the way, you have used a forward slash `/` in your answer; the actual notation regarding the answer is a tilde `~`, though your answer is still understandable, so this isn't a problem but more of a fun fact ;)